# I can't add animation to my babylonjs file

Tags: animation, gltf, babylonjs

i am new to babylonjs and currently having problem animating my gltf file. could you help me fix it? Thanks in advance

```
import * as BABYLON from '@babylonjs/core';
import '@babylonjs/loaders/glTF';
import { Inspector } from '@babylonjs/inspector';
import '@babylonjs/core/Animations/animatable';

const canvas = document.getElementById('renderCanvas');
const engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas);

const createScene = async function() {

const scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);

const camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera('camera', 1, 1, 8, new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0), scene);

camera.attachControl(true);

const light = new BABYLON.DirectionalLight('directionalLight', new BABYLON.Vector3(-2, -3, 0), scene);

const shadowGenerator = new BABYLON.ShadowGenerator(900, light);

BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMeshAsync('', '/', 'monas.gltf', scene).then((result) =\> {
const monasMeshes = result.meshes;
const monas = monasMeshes\[0\];
monas.scaling = new BABYLON.Vector3(0.25, 0.25, 0.25);

    console.log(monas);
    // Add rotation animation
    const animationBox = new BABYLON.Animation("rotationAnimation", "rotation.y", 30, BABYLON.Animation.ANIMATIONTYPE_FLOAT, BABYLON.Animation.ANIMATIONLOOPMODE_CYCLE);
    const keys = [];
    keys.push({ frame: 0, value: 0 });
    keys.push({ frame: 100, value: Math.PI * 2 });
    animationBox.setKeys(keys);
    monas.animations.push(animationBox);
    scene.beginAnimation(monas, 0, 100, true);
    shadowGenerator.addShadowCaster(monas);

});

return scene;
};

const scene = await createScene();
engine.runRenderLoop(function() {
scene.render();
});
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
engine.resize();
});
Inspector.Show(scene, {});
```

i have tried the code above and making some major changes but nothing seems to be working, i was hoping to create 2 animations for my monas.gltf. For your reference, my gltf file is from blender.

Comment: I would also like to add scaling to the monas, thank you!

Comment: Are you really looking to define the animation's movements with hard-coded numbers as shown here? Or would it be better to craft an animation using Blender's animation tools, and export that to glTF for playback here?